# How to include external library to jetty (start jetty by using start.jar)

Tags: memcached, jetty

I am trying to use jetty-nosql-memcached as jetty session backend.

jetty-nosql-memcached: https://github.com/yyuu/jetty-nosql-memcached

After I compiled the jar and put the file "jetty-nosql-memcached-0.4.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" into the following folder,

1. $JETTY_HOME/lib or
2. $JETTY_HOME/lib/ext or
3. $JETTY_BASE/lib or
4. $JETTY_BASE/lib/ext

Then I try to start up jetty, all the above setup throws the following exception:

ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.nosql.memcached.MemcachedSessionIdManager

I tried with an param after starts.jar

e.g. java -jar start.jar jetty.home=$JETTY_HOME

it successfully loads the class, however, it does not read the $JETTY_BASE war file anymore.  ($JETTY_HOME and $JETTY_BASE rested in different directories)

May I know what is the correct why to include an external library for Jetty?

Many thanks!

Add More information

## Jetty version

9.1.0.v20131115

Answer (score 2):

I figured out two ways to include external libraries

1. Add --lib=$EXTERNAL_LIB_LOCATION in the command line.

   > java -jar start.jar --lib=$EXTERNAL_LIB_LOCATION
2. Put the library in $JETTY_HOME\lib\ext, and start jetty in $JETTY_HOME

   > cd $JETTY_HOME
   >     java -jar start.jar